# Take N non-empty items from clojure set

Tags: collections, clojure

I have a set (I think) of items; similar to this:

```
(def a ({:answers 3 :comments 12} {} {} {:answers 43 :comments 23} {}))
```

I want to ideally remove all empty items in that list, but keep the set intact otherwise.. what I am trying to do is:

```
(defn drop-empty-items
 [a]
 (take-when #(not empty? %) a))
```

but this obviously doesn't work at all..

How do I do this, please?

I'm trying to return something to the effect of:

```
({:answers 3 :comments 12} {:answers 43 :comments 23})
```

from `drop-empty-items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(def a '({:answers 3 :comments 12} {} {} {:answers 43 :comments 23} {}))

(remove empty? a) 
;=> ({:answers 3, :comments 12} {:answers 43, :comments 23})
```

Comment: The `drop-empty-items` in the OP could be adapted to work - nest `empty %` into parenthesis and replace `take-when` with `filter`: `(defn drop-empty-items [a] (filter #(not (empty? %)) a))`

Comment: If you only want `n` non-empty items, then compose either with a `(take n (...))`.

Comment: * facepalm * I keep looking at wrong things.. thank you very much, will accept answer when time restriction ends.